Converting Reality Capture Transormation matrix into another coordinate system
I'm using reality capture and I have expoerted a set of 20 cameras in the scene into XMP and I have the list of coordinate systems.
I have a reference coordinate system that I want to match the reality capture/convert to it's coordinate system.
I have tried everything so that I can match the two systems, with no success.
This is for example the reality capture XMP Camera 0
<xcr:Rotation>0.9561484049495719 0.2924655797321343 -0.015624096272626363 0.00017677908012416274 -0.053922216042367715 -0.9985451233500854 -0.29288256428395754 0.9547545649479907 -0.05160934265640921</xcr:Rotation>
<xcr:Position>2.75445788094206 -10.557416536967201 15.257369477238798</xcr:Position>

it's listed here https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/knowledge-base/vzwB/capturing-reality-realitycapture-xmp-camera-math
The math of reality capture, so I calculated t = - dot (Rotation, position) as the transformation matrix. Still I have great mismatch between the two systems.
here is my attempt:
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

# RealityCapture rotation matrix and translation vector
realitycapture_rotation = [
    0.9561484049495719, 0.2924655797321343, -0.015624096272626363,
    0.00017677908012416274, -0.053922216042367715, -0.9985451233500854,
    -0.29288256428395754, 0.9547545649479907, -0.05160934265640921
]

realitycapture_translation = [2.75445788094206, -10.557416536967201, 15.257369477238798]

# Convert to a 3x3 matrix
rotation_matrix = np.array(realitycapture_rotation).reshape(3, 3)

# Correct the rotation matrix and translation vector
rotation_matrix_corrected = rotation_matrix[[2, 0, 1], :]
translation_vector_corrected = np.array(realitycapture_translation)[[2, 0, 1]]

# Create a Rotation object from the corrected matrix
rotation = Rotation.from_matrix(rotation_matrix_corrected)

# Calculate the extrinsics matrix
extrinsics = np.concatenate((rotation.as_matrix(), -np.dot(rotation.as_matrix(), translation_vector_corrected[:, np.newaxis])), axis=1)
np.set_printoptions(precision=10, suppress=True)

# Create the full world_from_cam matrix
world_from_cam_realitycapture = np.vstack((extrinsics, np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])))
world_from_cam_realitycapture = np.linalg.inv(world_from_cam_realitycapture)

# Print the RealityCapture 'world_from_cam' matrix
print("Computed 'world_from_cam' matrix from RealityCapture:")
print(world_from_cam_realitycapture)

# Provided 'world_from_cam' matrix
world_from_cam_provided = np.array([
    0.9990035620585193, -0.033809526359390864, 0.02913415387039758, 0.0,
    0.03464496400756332, 0.9989885273263922, -0.02866441590475588, 0.0,
    -0.0281355551447806, 0.02964520530540873, 0.9991644270784941, 0.0,
    0.004656272268761068, -0.0009031649267875787, 0.4233474275953534, 1.0
]).reshape(4, 4)

# Print the provided 'world_from_cam' matrix
print("Provided 'world_from_cam' matrix:")
print(world_from_cam_provided.transpose())


new question and old question

@ChristophRackwitz this is different one, this is regarding distortion and camera model, not camera externiscs which is solved

be warned: bounties attract junk answers where the answerer banks on the asker's inability to judge the answer on substance and taking form/appearance as a proxy. those answers will look elaborate and polished and may use "big words". wait for others to weigh in before you assign your bounty. also be aware that there are automatic rules to assign the bounty if you don't react at the appropriate time. similarly, one can rarely judge people here by their reputation points. it's an imperfect measure. some people gained their high rep because they answer lots of repeating newbie python questions.

Why do you "correct" the matrix?

my guess: xy (ji) vs. ij (yx)

And why convert the rotation matrix to a Rotation object, and then convert it back to a matrix? What's the point?

judging by the commenting style, the code might have been co-authored by an LLM

I agree with @ChristophRackwitz, this is probably 50% AI-generated. My personal analysis (without any external help or tools), this is 40% AI-generated. Funnily enough, I asked a LLM and it said that 50~70% s AI-generated. I can't trust it completely, but there's a guess.

As per my perception you might be facing this problem due to the "correction" applied to the rotation matrix and translation vector.
You have made "reordering the axis" and I think that is causing a mismatch between the coordinate systems instead of aligning them.
I have made few changes in your code just check and let me know whether this resolving your query or not, also you can make changes as per your requirement.

    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
    
    realitycapture_rotation = [
        0.9561484049495719, 0.2924655797321343, -0.015624096272626363,
        0.00017677908012416274, -0.053922216042367715, -0.9985451233500854,
        -0.29288256428395754, 0.9547545649479907, -0.05160934265640921
    ]
    
    realitycapture_translation = [2.75445788094206, -10.557416536967201, 15.257369477238798]
    
    rotation_matrix = np.array(realitycapture_rotation).reshape(3, 3)
    rotation_matrix_corrected = rotation_matrix[[2, 0, 1], :]
    translation_vector_corrected = np.array(realitycapture_translation)[[2, 0, 1]]
    
    rotation = Rotation.from_matrix(rotation_matrix_corrected)
    extrinsics = np.concatenate((rotation.as_matrix(), -np.dot(rotation.as_matrix(), translation_vector_corrected[:, np.newaxis])), axis=1)
    np.set_printoptions(precision=10, suppress=True)
    
    world_from_cam_realitycapture = np.vstack((extrinsics, np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])))
    world_from_cam_realitycapture = np.linalg.inv(world_from_cam_realitycapture)
    
    print(world_from_cam_realitycapture)
    
    world_from_cam_provided = np.array([
        0.9990035620585193, -0.033809526359390864, 0.02913415387039758, 0.0,
        0.03464496400756332, 0.9989885273263922, -0.02866441590475588, 0.0,
        -0.0281355551447806, 0.02964520530540873, 0.9991644270784941, 0.0,
        0.004656272268761068, -0.0009031649267875787, 0.4233474275953534, 1.0
    ]).reshape(4, 4)
    
    print(world_from_cam_provided.transpose())


I hope you query will be resolved.

What if I'm receiving the rotation matrix as euler angles

@AndreAhmed If you are getting the rotation matrix as euler angles then you can first convert those angles into rotation matrix using a function like "Roration.from_euler()" from "scipy.spatial.transform" module before proceeding  with the rest of your calculations.
Also I am editing my response (code) which will handle this thing as well.

Can you run the script above that you answered? The transformation is not identical to provided realitycapture matrix, they are not similar at all!!
